# Solving an ODE used in a nonhomogenous diffusion process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

A set of lecture notes from a PDE class say that the following ODE can be solved explicity:
$u_{t} + \lambda u = c$ for $t > 0$
where $c$ and $\lambda$ are constants,
$u(x, t) : [0,\pi] \times [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$,
and $u(x, 0) = u_{0}(x)$.

Can someone tell me which method from ODE should be used to solve this equation?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe $\large\lambda u$ is something likes
$\large-\lambda {\partial^{2}u \over \partial x^{2}}$. That's is what suggests the "diffusion" word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u$ is a function of $x$ and $t$ then that is not an ODE. However, if you are asking how to solve $y'+\lambda y=c$ for constants $\lambda,c$ then there are many ways. You could use separation of variables, the integrating factor technique or the method of annihilators. They all produce the same result: for $\lambda \neq 0$,
$$  y  = c_1e^{\lambda t} + \frac{c}{\lambda}.$$
To fit $y(t_o)=y_o$ we can simply solve for appropriate $c_1$ in the equation:
$$  y_o  = c_1e^{\lambda t_o} + \frac{c}{\lambda}. $$
All of this said, perhaps your question is actually how to solve $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\lambda u = c$?

Comment: Yes, $\partial_{t}u + \lambda u = c$.  The variable $x$ is meant to be fixed and in actuality $c$ is also a function of $x$.  I tried differentiating with respect to $t$ to clear the right hand side.  I'm not sure if that is the correct approach.

Comment: The method of using an integrating factor worked well.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.